# Cloaked Domain Forwarding

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to forward an url from my site, for example, `/freeyourself` to a specific IP address but I would like to keep my url the same (`/freeyourself`).

Is there any way I can do this via .htaccess? I've been trying a bit but without any luck.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could tell us the current contents of your .htaccess file? What have you tried already?

Answer (score 2):

Forwarding is for emails, does not mean much for web-pages.
You do not tell us about your use case, so the answer will be a bit vague.

If you want to serve a ressource from another domain to a client, you have 4 solutions.

**Frames and iframes**

Include the other domain's page inside the page you serve to your client, if the remote website allow it (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options).

**Redirection**: Telling your user's browser to go to a given URL. That is achieved with an HTTP 3xx code and can be written in .htaccess

```
# One file
Redirect 302 /oldfile.htm http://example.net/newfile.htm

# Folder
Redirect 302 / http://mt-example.com/
```

**Proxying**: Tell your webserver to download the page from the other domain, and serve that to the user's browser.

This will not work unless all links in the target page are relative etc...

```
# with mod_proxy
ProxyPass /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
```

**Proxying information instead of the page itself**:

With any web scripting language (python, php, ruby, ...) download the remote page, parse it, extract the relevant information that you need and create a new page from it.

Comment: Sorry for the vague description, what I mean is that I have an url: mysite.com/freeyourself and I want to show another page but without losing my original url. I know they call this cloaked domain forwarding but no idea how it works. Thanks.

Comment: after a google search, I think they mean the first solution. You can't do this with a .htaccess